# Find all numbers $a < 20$ so that $6a \equiv 16 \pmod {20}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all numbers $a < 20$ so that  $6a \equiv 16 \pmod {20}$

So far I have that $20 \mid 16-6a$ which implies $16 - 6a = 20q$ for some integer $q$. Then $8-3a=10q$ which means that $8 \equiv 3a \pmod{10}$. I do not understand what to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3a\equiv8\equiv8+10\equiv18\pmod {10}$

$a\equiv6\pmod{10}$

Can you proceed?

Comment: So this means that all numbers a≡6 (mod 10) that are less than 20 satisfy 6a≡16 (mod 20) correct?

Comment: @user2868727 That's true, but it does not follow from the way you derived the result, since your inferences are unidirectional, i.e. $\Rightarrow,\,$ not $\iff\!.\,$ So you'd need to verify that those values are in fact solutions, in order to complete your proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $  Kill the $\,3\,$ coefficient by multiplying both sides by $\, \dfrac{1}3 \equiv \dfrac{-9}3 \equiv -3\pmod{10}$